# Container of shared_ptr's but iterate with raw pointers

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a class that holds a list containing `boost::shared_ptrs` to objects of another class.

The class member functions that give access to the elemets in the list return raw pointers. For consistency I'd also like to be able to iterate with raw pointers instead of shared_ptrs. So when I dereference the list iterator, I'd like to get raw pointer, not a `shared_ptr`.

I assume I need to write a custom iterator for this. Is this correct? If so can someone point me in the right direction - I've never done this before.

Comment: Keep in mind that `shared_ptr`'s act like regular pointers (`*p` and `p->` both do The Right Thing).

Comment: I may be wrong, but providing both a raw pointer and a smart pointer looks like asking for trouble. Particularly, if the raw pointers allow writes. What sort of iterators are you looking for? If I were you, I'd probably begin with the simplest such as the `ForwardIterator`.

Comment: I know that `shared_ptr`'s behave the same with `*p` and `p->`. For a while I didn't really mind the difference. But it's a problem when it comes to the user interface. Other functions in the API take pointers as arguments. So if the user gets the object from an iterator he then needs to use `it->get()` to get the raw pointer. I suppose it doesn't matter much but from an end-user standpoint, there's no reason why the user should even know that the underlying object is held by a `shared_ptr`. So I'd like to make it consistent across the library.

Comment: Okay! So, even with your iterator class, the user will need to change his calls from `p` (for raw-pointers) to `*pi` (special iterators whose dereference operation provides the raw pointer). He'd still get to know something about your underlying representation. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: Getting a pointer by dereferencing an iterator is ugly for me.  I prefer a Boost.Indirect Iterator in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option using [Boost transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html):

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <tr1/memory>
#include <tr1/functional>

using std::list;
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;
using boost::transform_iterator;
using boost::make_transform_iterator;
using std::tr1::mem_fn;
using std::tr1::function;

struct Foo {};

struct Bar
{
  typedef shared_ptr< Foo > Ptr;
  typedef list< Ptr > List;
  typedef function< Foo* (Ptr) > Functor;
  typedef transform_iterator< Functor, List::iterator > Iterator;

  Iterator begin()
  {
    return make_transform_iterator( fooptrs.begin(), mem_fn( &Ptr::get ) );
  }

  Iterator end()
  {
    return make_transform_iterator( fooptrs.end(), mem_fn( &Ptr::get ) );
  }

  List fooptrs;
};
```

C++11 would make it easy to eliminate the `function` wrapper but I don't have a compiler handy to test it out.  You could also hide the concrete type of `Iterator` using type-erasure if you saw the need (I think Adobe offers a free `any_iterator` class template for this purpose.)

Comment: +1, and if getting references instead of pointers was acceptable (and I don't see why it shouldn't be), Boost also comes with [`indirect_iterator<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html).

Comment: Perfect. Great answer with great example.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes see people reaching for STL containers of `boost::shared_ptr` when actually the less obvious and relatively little known `boost::ptr_container` might be a better choice.

This may or may not be one of those cases, but consider that one of the nice properties of the `ptr_container` classes is that their iterators have [an "extra" indirection](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#indirected-interface) which helps keep things clean and safe.

Comment: Yes that's true. In this case however there actually will be shared ownership.

Answer (score 0):

‍♀️ ... zombie thread ...

If you can't use Boost (e.g., it's part of your public interface and you don't want to make that a requirement for your users), you can roll your own relatively easily. For a container `my_container` -- which could be a front for a standard, boost, whatever container but whose actual implementation is hidden in your implementation files and not exposed to your API -- holding any smart pointer to a class `my_type`, it would be something like:

```cpp
class iterator
{
public:
    ~iterator();

    iterator( const iterator& other );
    iterator& operator=( const iterator& other );

    // The standard iterator traits (names must be lower-case)
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    typedef my_type*                  value_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t            difference_type;
    typedef value_type*               pointer;
    typedef value_type                reference;

    iterator& operator++();
    iterator& operator++( int );
    reference operator*() const;

    friend bool operator==( const iterator& it1, const iterator& it2 );
    friend bool operator!=( const iterator& it1, const iterator& it2 );

private:
    // Private, type-erased construction
    friend class my_container;
    explicit iterator( void* );

    // Implementation hidden by pimpl
    struct impl;
    impl* _impl;
};
```

And in the cpp file, assuming we're using a `vector` of `shared_ptr` under the hood:

```cpp
// Define the Pimpl struct
struct iterator::impl
{
    typedef std::vector< std::shared_ptr<my_type> >::iterator iterator;
    iterator iter;
};

// Use void* as type erasure to hide the actual types from the user
iterator::iterator( void* wrappedIter )
    : _impl( new impl( *reinterpret_cast<impl::iterator*>( wrappedIter ) ) )
{
}

// Copying
iterator::iterator( const iterator& other )
    : _impl( new impl( *other._impl ) )
{}

iterator& iterator::operator=( const iterator& other )
{
    _impl->iter = other._impl->iter;
    return *this;
}

// ... could implement moving too ...

iterator::~iterator() 
{
    // Destroy the pimpl
    delete _impl;
}

iterator& iterator::operator++()
{
    ++_impl->iter;
    return *this;
}

iterator& iterator::operator++( int )
{
    ++_impl->iter;
    return *this;
}

iterator::reference iterator::operator*() const
{
    // This is where the magic happens: We convert the shared_ptr to a raw pointer.
    return _impl->iter->second.get();
}

bool operator==( const iterator& it1, const iterator& it2 )
{
    return *it1 == *it2;
}

bool operator!=( const iterator& it1, const iterator& it2 ) 
{ 
    return !( it1 == it2 ); 
}
```

Then all you need is a way to create these. To that end `my_container`'s `begin()`/`end()` functions would look like:

```cpp
my_container::iterator my_container::begin()
{
    // The & allows our type erasure by invoking our void* constructor
    auto iter = _data->vector.begin();
    return iterator( &iter );
}

my_container::iterator my_container::end()
{
    // The & allows our type erasure by invoking our void* constructor
    auto iter = _data->vector.end();
    return iterator( &iter );
}
```

That type erasure and taking the address of a member variable is a little dicey looking, but it's okay since we're immediately reinterpreting the `void*` and dereferencing and copying it.